# Is hyperbullet or bullet more common in online gameplay?

Tags: online-chess, statistics, lichess, bullet-chess

On [Lichess](https://lichess.org/), the shortest form of bullet is named hyperbullet. It is essentially 30-second chess. Standard bullet is 1 to 3 minutes.

It is difficult to assess popularity without invoking opinion. **Instead, which time control results in more games played, or has a higher number of players?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Lichess, there were

- 16,664 [UltraBullet players this week](https://lichess.org/stat/rating/distribution/ultraBullet), and
- 361,848 [Bullet players this week](https://lichess.org/stat/rating/distribution/bullet).

As for games played, since January 2021 there were

- 7,111,572 UltraBullet games played, and
- 55,343,894 Bullet games played. <sup>(1)</sup>

**Historical Data:**  <sup>(1)</sup> 
[image: Historical data on number of games played by time control on Lichess]

**Cautionary Note:** Examining the number of games by time control may be misleading since one can play more games of ultrabullet than bullet in the same amount of time. More relevant to the original "popularity" inquiry may be the total amount of time spent playing, but this data is less accessible.

<sub>(1) [Lichess Opening Explorer](https://lichess.org/analysis#explorer).</sub>